# How do I change all the keys of a Python dictionary, if the values of said keys are nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, unit-testing, dictionary, key

I am working on a headache of a college project in Python, and one of the functions basically has to write a dictionary (which cointains nested dictionaries) into a csv file, and later read from the said file, place it into a new dictionary, and return that new dictionary to the user.

Now, the keys of the said dictionary are of type **int**, but obvsiouly after being read from the file and written into the new dictionary, they turn into type **str**.

The unittests we were given keep failing my function because of this, as they expect the same value that was given to us originally, so I have been struggling with modifying this. Below is a (hand-crafted) example of that dictionary that I was practicing on, but still couldn't seem to get the change to take place:

```
dictionary = {
    "0": {
        "name": "gary",
        "last_name": "john",
        "age": 13
    },
    "1": {
        "name": "larry",
        "last_name": "boyle",
        "age": 10
    },
    "2": {
        "name": "banji",
        "last_name": "buas",
        "age": 20
    }
}

for i in dictionary.items(): #this gives us a tuple
    change = list(i) #convert tuple to list
    change[0] = int(change[0]) #change each str to int
    i = tuple(change) #convert back to tuple
```

This approach only seems to work within the for-loop, but as soon as the loop ends, and I try printing out the 'new' dict, all I get is the same old one. Can anyone help with this problem?

Comment: Nowhere in your loop do you modify the dictionary. Where do you *expect* you dictionary to be modified? Note, you should probably just create *a new dictionary*.  It looks like you just want `new_dict = {int(k):v for k,v in dictionary.items()}`

Comment: " obvsiouly after being read from the file and written into the new dictionary, they turn into type str." that isn't obvious at all. Perhaps when you create the *original dictionary* **you** should just make the keys ints instead of strings. Or just do the conversion after, using the code above.

Comment: "write a dictionary (which cointains nested dictionaries) into a csv file" - That doesn't look like a very good choice of format... Why not something like JSON?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille although, JSON won't allow integer keys in JSON objects, so that problem will remain, but yes, good point

Comment: _...into a csv file..._: CSV does not know types, just strings.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Right, good point!

Comment: Hey everyone! I now realize that I did a big dumb dumb, and the first comment worked the trick. However, I must ask a follow-up: is this the standard method of changing keys in a dictionary, or is this specific for my question (not the int() part, I understand that was added just for my question, but the whole k:v thing in general)?

Comment: @UrosDjosic note, that doesn't actually *change the keys in a dictionary*, it creates a *new dictionary with a new set of keys from the old dictionary*. If you actually wanted to "change" a key, you have to *add* the new key-value pair and delete the old key-value pair. Which is unweidly (and in my mind I would be worried about what that would do to the internals of the dictionary, better to just create a new object).

Comment: But in general, creating a new container, `list`, `dict`, `set`, `tuple` etc instead of modifying the orignal one is common practice and almost always a good approach (unless your program is designed, poorly IMO, around a particular object being mutated)